# How to identify a double \n\n with fgets/read/fread

Tags: c, file, graph, buffer, dot

I have a dot file, which i need to parse it into a graph structure using C.

My dot file contains 2 blocs seperated with a double \n:

- the one is verticle
- the other one is edges

I have tried with fgets since it reads until \n is met. It is helpfull to count the number of verticles but not whats comes after it. I don't have any idea of how i can do it

Right now I have a function like this (not complete)

```c
int graphe_charger_dot(graphe *g, char *nom_fichier) {
  FILE * f;
  int n;
  if ((f = fopen(nom_fichier, "r")) == 0) {
    puts(nom_fichier);
    puts("Erreur d'ouverture du fichier");
    return -1;
  }

  char buffer[500];

  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer),f);
;
  if (strcmp(buffer, "graph {\n") != 0) {
    puts("Erreur de compatibilité de fichier");
    puts(nom_fichier);
    return -1;
  }
  puts("Fichier ouvert et compatible");
  puts("Lecture du buffer 1");

  // reads the first verticles. the atoi is just here to test if i can convert an char to integer even with a non integer right after it. 
  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer),f);
  n = atoi(buffer);
  g->n += 1;

  return 0;
}
```

My dot file

```
graph {
  0;
  1;
  2;
  3;
  4;
  5;
  6;
  7;
  8;


  0 -- 1;
  0 -- 4;
  0 -- 5;
  0 -- 6;
  0 -- 8;
  1 -- 2;
  1 -- 3;
  1 -- 4;
  1 -- 5;
  2 -- 3;
  2 -- 4;
  2 -- 5;
  2 -- 8;
  3 -- 7;
  5 -- 7;
  5 -- 8;
  6 -- 8;
  7 -- 8;
}
```

and the structure of the graph

```c
struct s_graphe {
  int n;                /* number of verticles */
  int m;                /* number of edges */
  int adj[GRAPHE_ORDRE_MAX][GRAPHE_ORDRE_MAX];
  /* Adjacency matrix of the graph */
};
```

Comment: If `fget()` returns a string that's equal to `"\n"` then you read an empty line.

Comment: @Barmar is correct. The alternative is to `getc` then if the next char isn't another newline, put it back with `ungetc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to identify a double \n\n ...

The prior line ended with a `'\n'`.  With `fgets()`, test if `buffer[0] == '\n'` to see if a line begins and ends with a `'\n'` to detect the consecutive  `'\n'`.

```
  ...
  puts("Lecture du buffer 1");

  //fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer),f);
  //n = atoi(buffer);
  //g->n += 1;

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) && buffer[0] != '\n') {
    // parse `buffer` for a vertex
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f)) {
    // parse `buffer` for an edge
  }
```

---

> My dot file contains 2 blocs separated with a double \n:

The below looks like **3** `'\n'` in a row.  The first of the 3 ends the `"8;\n"` line.

```
7;\n
8;\n
\n
\n
0 -- 1;\n
0 -- 4;\n
```

In that case a little more work is needed.  Perhaps

```
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f) && buffer[0] != '\n') {
    // parse `buffer` for a vertex
  }

  // Here code consumes 0 or more lines that are only `"\n"`
  // Could use a counter to limit
  int ch;
  while ((c = fgetc(f)) == '\n');
  ungetc(ch, f);

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f)) {
    // parse `buffer` for an edge
  }
```